# Formatting data in R?

Tags: r, formatting

How do I format dates in R? I had to change something in my data set to account for blanks, and now my dates are very large negative numbers. I need to change them back into dates.

Comment: Can you upload an example

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `\t` delimited input file.

Use the `as.is` argument to stop the `read.table()` function from  converting the input variables. Then perhaps convert the date into something usable using `strptime()`

```
data <- read.table(file="...", sep="\t", as.is = TRUE)

data[,1] <- strptime(data[,1], "%Y-%m-%d")
```